# Ember JS Loading and Error Substates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, lazy-loading, loading, handlebars.js

I want to confirm the approach here. Every relationship in my models is asychronous/lazy-loaded. While records are rendering, the handlebars template is showing prior to having its data populated to the screen. In the dummy example below, the red border shows up for all users in the group, and there's a noticeable delay in getting them all populated.

I've checked out http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/ and don't think I need a blank loading template (please correct me if I'm wrong); I just want to show an empty section, and the templates (here: red border and name) popup only when the user's name is populated.

```
Models.User = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr("string"),
  firstName: DS.attr("string"),
  group: DS.belongsTo("group", {async: true})
});

Models.Group = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  users: DS.hasMany("user", { async: true }),
});

{{#each user in group}}
  {{#if user.isLoaded }} {{!-- I've also tried user.isFulfilled, user.firstName, user.email --}}
    <div style="border: #f00 solid 1px;">
      {{user.firstName}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at jsbin http://jsbin.com/wenuy/2/edit

Explanation:

The search form (contains search text box and submit button is constant). Based on the search word, the section which shows results is getting changed.

I have used isLoading property. The idea is before making a call to server set it to true i.e, loading message. Then on success of request (i.e, server is responded with required data) set it to false, so that 'loading' message get hide and result section get displayed.

Comment: Thanks @Susai. I followed your example, and in my case changed the above to `{{#unless isLoading }} ... {{/unless}}` since I didn't need the "Loading..." portion. Thanks again!